# Prove existence of a bijective combined function given 2 separate bijective functions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Prove if there exists a bijective function from $A$ to $C$ and a bijective function from $B$ to $D$, then there exists a bijective function from $A \times B$ to $C \times D$. Here, $A \times B$ refers to the set $\{(a,b) | a \in A, b \in B\}$ and $C \times D$ refers to the set $\{(c,d) | c \in C, d \in D\}$.

Comment: Can you make a guess as to a suitable candidate function?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know one but even if I do, I may be making assumptions on the functions.

Comment: You can assume there is a bijection $f:A\to C$, and another bijection $g:B\to D$. So the question is how to combine these two to get a bijection $h:A\times B\to C\times D$. A typical member of $A\times B$ is $(a,b)$. So what would you expect $h(a,b)$ to be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. If $f : A \rightarrow C$ and $g : B \rightarrow D$, then 
$(a,b) \mapsto (f(a),g(b))$ is a bijection.